# Zimbra - How to extend ui and core functionality

Tags: email, user-interface, reverse-engineering, javadoc, zimbra

OK , i have a server that uses [zimbra](http://www.zimbra.com/) as a mail service ! i`m new in zimbra and trying to know the structure of it and know how i can add some functionality, all thing that i interest to know is where i can change the web client source and deface the mail box of web client and is the zimbra uses java script to create UI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mainly your documentation-source would be the official [Zimbra Wiki](http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Main_Page).
In order to extend / modify Zimbra you need to get the [source](http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Building_Zimbra_using_Perforce#Building_.22Nighties.22) and [setup your dev env](http://blog.zimbra.com/blog/archives/2005/08/setting-up-a-zimbra-development-environment.html) according the docu.

To modify the web client, you have to look into `/zcs-src/ZimbraWebClient` and yes, Zimbra uses Java Script. Take a look at tutorials for Zimlets creation ([for example](http://blog.zimbra.com/blog/archives/2010/01/adding-tab-applications-to-the-zimbra-web-client.html)) to get started.